# How do i fetch date and time from MySQL table row

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, fetch

i found an old blog script (very old) kicking around on my PC. im having troubles with fetching the date and time from my DB to display in PHP. Can someone help me.
This is my MySQL DB setup.

```
CREATE TABLE blog_posts (
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  title varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  news text NOT NULL,
  poster varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  date timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

And this is what im using to send a post:

```
<?php

include "db.php";   
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $news=$_POST['news'];
    $poster=$_POST['poster'];

    $query="INSERT INTO $blogposts (title, news, poster) VALUES ('$title', '$news', '$poster')";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    mysql_close();

    header("Location: post.php");
?>
```

And finally this is what im using to call the date on the front-end:

```
<?php echo "posted on: - ".$day.".".$month.".".$year." at ".$hour.":".$min; ?>
```

I'm no expert (clearly) but the call for the date doesnt look right to me. Anyone have any ideas on how i could make it work, or even make it better??

EDIT::

```
<?php

    include "db.php";

//query
    $query="SELECT * FROM ".$blogposts." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,$limit ";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

//loop
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
$querycomment = "SELECT ID FROM ".$newscomments." WHERE newsid=".$row['id'];
$resultcomment=mysql_query($querycomment) or die (mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($resultcomment);

    ereg("^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})",$row['date'],$res);
    $year=$res[1];
    $month=$res[2];
    $day=$res[3];
    $hour=$res[4];
    $min=$res[5];
    $sec=$res[6];


?>
```

Thanks

Comment: for the record, i tried changing the call to `<?php echo "posted on: - ".$day.".".$month.".".$year." at ".$hour.":".$min."; ?>` but it had a error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As date column has TIMESTAMP data type and got not null constraint so it will have default current_timestamp value if no data posted on date column while inserting. [see mysql timestamp ref manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html).

So to achieve a result that you ask you can try fetch that data by using code like this:

```
$sql = "select id, title, news, poster, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d.%m.%Y at %k:%i') as posteddate from blog_posts";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["title"]."<br/>";
    echo "By : " . $row["poster"]."<br/>";
    echo "posted on: -  " . $row["posteddate"]."<br/>"; //"posted on: - 03.03.2011 at 7:35"
}
```

Comment: it returns an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%' in.." from DATE_FORMAT line

Comment: im guessing this is because i dnt have MySQL v5.5

Comment: IMHO by reading mysql refman even from the oldest version it has DATE_FORMAT function see [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: ups sorry my mistake the error caused by double quotes on my sql date_format parameter. I have update the code example. The change are from `DATE_FORMAT(date,"%d.%m.%Y at %k:%i")` to `DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d.%m.%Y at %k:%i')`

Comment: my friend. a work of genius in my eyes!! thanks. worked a treat.

Comment: Thank you. it is nice to help a fellow php programmer like you.

Comment: after a bit of searching, i found a nice way to format the date output in PHP. use this instead: `<?php print date('d M y ', strtotime($row['date'])); ?>` and get rid of the DATE_FORMAT function in MySQL, and simply call the row 'date'

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be adding any value to the date field in your insert command. You could use [`now()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) to add the current time stamp to add the current time during the insert. To extract the time you could either (a) read the date field from the table and format the time using PHP or (b) get formatted fields of the time stamp in the select command using the [mysql date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

You also need to have some code to read the values in your PHP to read the values for the fields. This seems to be missing in your question.

Comment: ok, im struggling to grasp what your saying. ill take a look at the website. EDIT:: had a look and havent a clue. im reading the other rows fine. `<?php echo $row['news']; ?>` for example. its just the date im having trouble with

Comment: You might need to read through a few PHP MySQL tutorials on how to read data from the tables. May be this will help http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql/4

Comment: Have you checked the data in your table to see whether the date filed actually has values. As I mentioned, your insert does not add any data to the table. If your date field is null, you won't get any output.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you haven't defined any of the date variables, that you're trying to use?

Comment: i was thinking this, there seems to be a chunk missing from the code

Comment: Yes, the part on reading the data back is missing in your question.